# Why doesn't underscore prefer typeof in some cases?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Per Crockford's, The Good Parts

> typeof is accurate for function, string, number, boolean, and
>   undefined.  null and array are both incorrectly reported as object.

So why not use typeof for the cases in which it does work?  It is always faster that is why I wonder why it is not preferred in these cases.

Particularly here for function, string and number.

http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-111

```
  each(['Arguments', 'Function', 'String', 'Number', 'Date', 'RegExp'], function(name) {
    _['is' + name] = function(obj) {
      return toString.call(obj) == '[object ' + name + ']';
    };   });
```

Comment: I don't think there's a real reason other than readability and shorter code. Checkout Lodash if you want performance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does UnderscoreJS use toString.call() instead of typeof?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10394929/why-does-underscorejs-use-tostring-call-instead-of-typeof)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point of these wrappers is to catch boxed value objects.

`typeof new Number(1) === 'object'`

Comment: Are there any cases when you would want to use typeof in a library?

Comment: @www.arcmarks.com: If you don't want to allow boxed objects.

Comment: I was under the impression that you should not use boxed object in general as there in not a need for them.  Do you know of any uses for boxed objects? that is why use `new Number(1)` instead of just `1`